# Register a reactor to trigger on a custom parameter with the API?

Tags: revit-api, revit

I have a reactor that has to react to changes done upon a custom parameter. When you register the reactor, you specify the type of change it reacts to.

```
UpdaterRegistry.AddTrigger(updaterId, RevitFilters.StructuralElementsFilter, Element.GetChangeTypeAny());
```

The following are the changetypes allowed by the API:

```
public static ChangeType GetChangeTypeAny();
public static ChangeType GetChangeTypeElementAddition();
public static ChangeType GetChangeTypeElementDeletion();
public static ChangeType GetChangeTypeGeometry();
public static ChangeType GetChangeTypeParameter(ElementId parameterId);
public static ChangeType GetChangeTypeParameter(Parameter param);
```

I'd like to use `GetChangeTypeParameter(Parameter param)` or `ChangeType GetChangeTypeParameter(ElementId parameterId)` but I didn't find a proper way so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard a couple of times that these methods apparently do not work. The workaround is to use `GetChangeTypeAny` instead. Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

That [AddTrigger](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/776a59e3-3214-8250-64ca-41ec913257d5.htm) method only works with CategoryFilter and ParameterFilter.

If you want to handle both change types then register for each in a separate call:

```
UpdaterRegistry.AddTrigger(..., ..., changeType1);
UpdaterRegistry.AddTrigger(..., ..., changeType2);
```

Alternatively you can combine change types via

```
Autodesk.Revit.DB.ChangeType.ConcatenateChangeTypes(changeType1, changeType2)
```